# Appropriate settings for rails actionmailer to send through cPanel smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138699/sending-email-ruby-on-rails-dev-environment-smtp-cpanel) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), but there is not a lot else to help me specifically configure actionmailer settings to work with cPanel hosting. Ultimately, all I want to do is have an email sent to users when they sign up. I have been able to get an email to send when running the app in development using localhost and a gmail account, and in production using a gmail account, but not in production using my actual domain's email account (i.e. info@mydomain.com).

I have checked that info@mydomain.com can send and receive mail by doing so manually.

I have tried all sorts of permutations of the following, with no luck:

- address: mail.mydomain.com (as per cPanel instructions for outgoing
  server)
- port: 465 as per cPanel instructions for outgoing server, but also 25 and 587
  for good measure
- authentication: plain, login
- with and without openssl_verify_mode: 'none'

The rest of my settings look like this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
   address: "mail.mydomain.com",
   port: 465, 
   domain: "myapp.herokuapp.com",
   authentication: "plain",
   enable_starttls_auto: true,
   user_name: "info@mydomain.com",
   password: "password", 
   openssl_verify_mode: 'none' 
 }
```

I have spent 6 hours simply trying permutation after permutation and searching settings in heroku, the hosting and in my code for possible problems, but so far cannot work out why I cannot get an email to send

Comment: Did you try port 587 (as per your first link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138699/sending-email-ruby-on-rails-dev-environment-smtp-cpanel) ? (Just double-checking as you haven't said you tried that)

Comment: Thanks for spotting - yes I tried 587 (have adjusted question to reflect this)